# show form action page

Tags: jquery, forms, action, submission

I am trying to move my first steps in jquery and I need help.

in classic asp if I submit a form with action="retrievepage.asp" the user is redirected to the page that is specified in action. In this way I can retrieve (for my personal checks, for example) the fields' value using request.form.

I am trying to do the same with jquery but for sure I am making a mistake.

on onsubmit of my form I have the following code

```
  onSubmit: function(invalid, e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#invalid')
      .show()
      .toggleClass('valid', ! invalid)
      .text(invalid ? (invalid +' invalid fields') : 'All good!');

      if(!invalid) {
        $.post('retrievepage.asp', this.$form.serialize(), function(response) { alert("Submitted");
        }); // read as JSON
      }


  }
```

Instead of the alert I would like to have shown the destination page (retrievepage.asp) in order to check the results of the submission.
How can I do?

Thank you!

Comment: The destination page HTML is in `response`.

Comment: Mmmm... I am sorry but probably I need some more info to understand..

Comment: Try `console.log(response);` instead of alerting, to see what the ASP page returned.